# Arguments for Node child_process "spawn()"

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell, child-process

Using child_process (spawn) to open a new BASH terminal and execute the commands in each file.

I want to add all of my .sh files, that I'm going to spawn, into a folder to clean up my project directory.

PROBLEM:
I can't figure out how to change the directory the scripts run from, and the docs are a little to heavy for me at this point.

SIMPLE TEST EXAMPLE, WITH MY FIRST TWO FILES FOR CONNECTING (each .sh file would be in the project folder):

```
    const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

    const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'connect.sh']);

/*
    <connect.sh> // 1st .sh file
    #!/usr/bin/env bash  //to make it bash
    HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5002 PEERS=ws://localhost:5001 npm run dev

    <connect1.sh> // 2nd .sh file
    #!/usr/bin/env bash   //to make it bash
    HTTP_PORT=3003 P2P_PORT=5003 PEERS=ws://localhost:5002,ws://localhost:5001 npm run dev
*/
```

I have 9 of these files to connect up to 10 peers. And I would like to put them in a folder to simplify my project structure.

This is my actual API call below....
// Uses length to determine which file to run

```
     app.post("/peers/connect", async function (req, res) {
      const peerInfo = await peers.info();
      // no peers yet
      if (typeof peerInfo === "string") {
        let bat = spawn("cmd.exe", ["/c", "connect.sh"]);
        res.json("A new terminal has opened! You are now connected!");
      } else { 
        // peers exist
        let length = peerInfo.peers;
        // console.log(length);
        let bat = spawn("cmd.exe", ["/c", `connect${length}.sh`]);
        res.json("A new terminal has opened! You are now connected!");
      }
    });
```

My file structure here...you can see why I want a folder for these!

[image: My file structure]

RECAP:
Help my put all of these files into a folder (shellScripts) and have the code still work :)
Thanks! (just realized we might have to cd back into project folder before "npm run dev" in each file?)

Comment: Just use ``spawn("cmd.exe", ["/c", `folder/connect${length}.sh`]);``?

Comment: Why are you spawning a `cmd` to run a `bash` script?!

Comment: Extra Credit/Alternative: if anyone knows how to dynamically create a .sh file so I could have infinite peers, that would be great! Or another method of opening up a terminal and entering a dynamic command!

Comment: @Bergi I tried just adding the folder directory in front and it doesn't do anything! Also, I just prefer bash, the code will spawn a bash terminal :) (the first line in each .sh file makes it bash).  and I also don't know how to run my bash command in a normal powershell EDIT: I also tried "../shellScipts/my.sh"

Comment: "*if anyone knows how to dynamically create a .sh file so I could have infinite peers*" - use only a single script and parameterise it properly. But really, just don't use `.sh` scripts at all! All your script does is call a single command - you can (and should) just spawn that directly.

Comment: @Bergi so your saying instead of spawning the file, spawn the command? And what would be the alternative to using .sh? Still pretty new to programming and command line stuff

Answer (score 0):

You are using the cmd.exe utility to run a .sh file, but that wont work. You have to install a bash interpreter on your windows device or install WSL. (If necessary add bash.exe to the windows path) Then change your code to this:

```js
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');
const bat = spawn('bash.exe',['connect.sh']);
```

I hope this answer helped

For running multiple files:

```js
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');
const fs = require("node:fs")
const dir = "" // Replace this with the location of the directory containing connect shellscripts

let entrys = fs.readdirSync(dir)
entrys = entrys.filter(v => v.startsWith("connect"))

for (let ent of entrys) {
  const bat = spawn('bash.exe',[ent]);
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: The code actually works perfectly fine! Not sure if its the comment on first line of each .sh file??  #!/usr/bin/env bash        But I'll try your code out in the morning thank you. I've found in the meanwhile that "exec" will automatically open a terminal so temporarily I've adjust the code to.....var {spawn, exec} = require('child_process');
let bat = exec( "connect.sh"); This works the same as my old code.  I'm still a student and the whole child_process thing is something I came across today on my own. Thanks again

Comment: @TaylorLepper Thanks, if the answer helped you, please put an upvote on my answer, i would like it :)

Comment: I don't have enough rep yet! 2 points away. I'll try to remember when I get enough rep :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer on me own. Thanks to everyone that tried to help :)
And to those saying my above code doesn't work, it works perfectly fine.

I've provided a picture to clarify. 1st is what the code below produces. 2nd is manually pasting it into GIT BASH.

```
// test.js in project structure pic above
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var path = require('path')

var parentDir = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'shellScripts');
exec('my.sh', {cwd: parentDir}, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  // if you also want to change current process working directory:
  process.chdir(parentDir);
});
```

This is what the code produces.
[image: Pic 1. Code output]

And this is opening a GIT BASH in project folder and pasting the command in

[image: Pic 2. Manual GIT BASH]